# Cupertino Datepicker not rendering correctly in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

I started a new project to make sure that the current project I was working on wasn't corrupted, but the widget still doesn't render correctly.
This happened after trying to update flutter whilst trying to fix other issues.
The months, dates, and years aren't showing up as they normally do for this widget
Any ideas, on what could be going wrong would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Sizes itself to its parent and may not render correctly if not given the full screen width. "  Are you giving it full width?

Comment: Yes I am. it functions okay, its just not rendering the top part and bottom part, and the height is half the screen